# HTC One X was dropped and now it doesn't charge or turn on

Tags: charging, htc-one-x

Last night, my HTC One X was dropped. Suddenly, it became so hot at the back and on the screen. After an hour or so, the phone started to cool down.

But, it doesn't charge or turn on; even the charging lamp didn't turn on too. I used all the diffrent forms of turning on with the volume buttons and without it, but the phone is still off.

What should I do?

Comment: Try to return in for a warranty replacement if you can.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the battery may have become damage or shorted. You really need to return it and get it replaced. I would strongly advise against opening it up yourself - the battery sounds like it won't be safe - and ask a shop to remove the SIM and memory cards for you. @Ryan Conrad deserves credit for his comment too.